# mysql column count doesn't match value count (redux): yes it does. or does it?

Tags: mysql

Is MySQL giving me grief because the nested SELECT in the insert statement uses the COUNT(*) function instead of selecting an actual column? So, what's the workaround?

Here's the story:

```
mysql> explain test;
+----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| language | varchar(50)          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| count    | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT languages.name, COUNT(*) AS `total` FROM languages JOIN events ON languages.id     = events.language_id GROUP BY name HAVING total > 250 ORDER BY total DESC;
+-----------+-------+
| name      | total |
+-----------+-------+
| Spanish   | 60079 |
| Foochow   |  2838 |
| Mandarin  |  2396 |
| Russian   |  1675 |
| Arabic    |  1410 |
| Cantonese |  1358 |
| Korean    |   736 |
| French    |   531 |
| Punjabi   |   426 |
| Urdu      |   408 |
| Hebrew    |   276 |
| Pashto    |   255 |
+-----------+-------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test (`language`,`count`) VALUES ((SELECT languages.`name`, COUNT(*) AS `total` FROM languages JOIN events ON languages.id = events.language_id GROUP BY name HAVING total > 250 ORDER BY total DESC));
ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't support this sort of multiple-column-returning subquery, so the error message you're seeing is because the `VALUES` clause only contains one subquery, which is perforce (in a sense) only one column.

To fix it, you can skip the `VALUES` syntax, and just write:

```
INSERT
  INTO test (`language`,`count`)
SELECT languages.`name`, COUNT(*) AS `total`
  FROM languages
  JOIN events
    ON languages.id = events.language_id
 GROUP
    BY name
HAVING total > 250
 ORDER
    BY total DESC
;
```

(See [§13.2.5.1 "`INSERT ... SELECT` Syntax" in the *MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html).)

Answer (score 0):

> INSERT INTO test (`language`,`count`)

should be

```
INSERT INTO test (language,count)
```